# Путь по умолчанию File.Exists(path)

Tags: c#, .net

Если в `File.Exists(path)`,  в `path` передать только имя файла, то где он будет его искать по дефолту?

Проблема возникла в WCF-сервисе. Может это важно.

Comment: Там, куда в данный момент смотрит `Environment.CurrentDirectory`

Comment: да, и это c:\windows\system32\inetsrv

Comment: Почитайте про них в википедии https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83, почитайте какие-нибудь основы ОС раздел файловая система прямые и относительные пути.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Относительный путь к файлу считается от текущей директории, которую можно получить с помощью [`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx).

Из документации:

> Gets the current working directory of the application.

Чтобы не гадать и не разбираться в тонкостях путей можно вызвать [`Path.GetFullPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx), который преобразует относительный путь в абсолютный:

```
if(!File.Exists(relativePath))
{
    string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(relativePath);
    //включаем его в сообщение об ошибке, в логи и т.п.
```

Answer (score -4):

Будет искать в той же директории, где расположен исполняемый файл вашего WCF-сервиса.

Comment: Уверены, что это будет в 100% случаев?

Comment: Это, к сожалению, неверно. Текущий каталог может быть любым.